# Echo success on delete mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table. My PHP script is suppose to return `true` if a row get deleted. But, I am getting `true`, no matter whether the row get deleted or not. I am posting the code below;

```
$query = "delete from mytable where qwerty='asdf'";
$delete = mysql_query($query);

if($delete){
  echo "true";
}else{
  echo "false";
}
```

I want to echo `true` if row get deleted and `false` if not get deleted. How can I do this?

Comment: you will get true (or "not false") from mysql if query has been executed correctly. note: in interpreted languages (script languages) normally everything that is not false is boolean true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php), you should use use [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php):

```
mysql_query('delete from mytable where qwerty='asdf'');
printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

That way, you can check out how many records were affected by your command. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: can u post a specific solution. Just want to echo `true` if row is deleted and echo `false` if not deleted.. Thanks..

Comment: Seriously? Can't you hack a solution with the pointers given here? Get `mysql_affected_rows()` into a variable and test the variable value. If greater than ZERO, you have your "true", else you have your FALSE. There you go.

Comment: BTW, guess what's is the first page that comes up in Google when you type the words `php mysql delete count`? There's no **free work done for you** here. There's a lot of pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error. Use  mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mysql_affected_rows` function to find out if any rows were actually deleted.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: can u post a specific solution. Just want to echo true if row is deleted and echo false if not deleted.. Thanks..